# Programming 0s along a diagonal

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have a matrix flattened into a 1-d array. How can I, put `0` in all of the diagonals? Example, for a `4x4` matrix, I tried this (`n=4`)

```
int j = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            global_matrix[i + j] = 0;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

but I get this

```
|       0       |       61      |       64      |       80      |
|       0       |       16      |       35      |       15      |
|       0       |       74      |       7       |       68      |
|       0       |       54      |       92      |       63      |
```

Comment: Use the index calculation `x + y * width` and two for loops for y and x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to loop over all elements for this, and use a condition to decide which ones are on the diagonal. A simple loop over the `n` diagonal elements will do.

The key observation is that the diagonal element shifts by one position every time you move to the next row. So if you look at the indices of all diagonal elements, they are spaced by `n + 1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    global_matrix[i * (n + 1)] = 0;
}
```

Another way of deriving this: When accessing element `(i, k)` in a matrix stored in a 1D array, the index calculation is `i * n + k`. For diagonal elements, `i` and `k` are equal, so this expression becomes `i * n + i`. Applying basic algebra, this is equal to `i * (n + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize j=0, and its working on my machine

```
int main()
{
    int j = 0, n=4, global_matrix[16]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

    for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            global_matrix[i + j] = 0;
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
        cout<<global_matrix[i];
    return 0;
}
```